# KeystoneJS updateItems , keystone.updateItem is not a function TypeError: keystone.updateItem is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

Is there such thing as updateItems in Keystone JS , just like createItems ? I've tried the ff update code below but it fired an error keystone.updateItem is not a function TypeError: keystone.updateItem is not a function.

## createItems - which is working

```
 keystone.createItems({
        Vehicle: postJson
      }, function (err, stats) {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        res.json({
          data: stats.message
        });

        console.log("Succeeded!!")
      });
```

## What i have tried

```
 keystone.updateItem ({
                Vehicle: user
              }, function (err, stats) {
                if (err) return res.json(err);
                res.json({
                  data: stats.message
                });

                console.log("Succeeded!!")
              });
```

Comment: How are you defining the variable `keystone` ..can you post that code?

Comment: can you open a chat Sir ?

Comment: so i can easily address the quesion

Comment: Actually the data came from the csv which i did parsed to json array object and then wanted to use those data to update data in the database

Comment: if you can open the chat i can show you the whole code

Comment: I have some issue which I am not technically familiar with the update handler of keystone

Comment: @EmmanuelNK ,  ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Keystone is based off Mongoose models, shouldn't `updateItem` take two parameters:

```js
const itemToUpdate = {
  id: userID
}

const fieldToUpdate = {
  Vehicle: user
}

keystone.updateItem(
  itemToUpdate, 
  fieldToUpdate, 
function(err, stats) {
  if (err) return res.json(err);
  res.json({
    data: stats.message
  });

  console.log("Succeeded!!")
})
```

where `itemToUpdate` is the query to match the document you want to update and the `fieldToUpdate` is the object containing the field/fields you want a new value for. Something like this.

Comment: same error keystone.updateItem is not a function TypeError: keystone.updateItem is not a function

Comment: can you open a chat in stackoverflow ?

Comment: I will update the code

Comment: can you go back to the chat sir ?